# Error when running R script from Python

Tags: python, r

I want to call an R script from my python application.
I have tried the subprocess and the rpy2, and both gave me the same error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I think the problem is in the R path in the environment variables, so these are the R entries in the PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\Rscript;
```

And these are my two pieces of code that give the same problem:

### RPY2

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

ro.r('x=c()')
ro.r('x[1]=22')
ro.r('x[2]=44')
print(ro.r('x'))
```

This code gives the error in the import line

### subprocess

```
import subprocess

command = 'Rscript'
path2script = 'maximum.R'
args = ['11', '3', '9', '42']
cmd = [command, path2script] + args
x = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)

print('The maximum of the numbers is:', x)
```

This code gives the error in the calling of the subprocess line.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried calling Rscript from the absolute path?

Comment: Try calling - Rscript maximum.R <Arguments> - from new command prompt.

Comment: @snaut Yea it worked to call the absolute path of the Rscript!! thanks :D
I don't know why I didn't think about this before